# How to update TextView in Navigation Header from Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, navigation-drawer

The changes to a TextView in Navigation header won't update do the UI. All of this is executed on the UI thread. The values of TextView are user specific, so I need to set them from the Activity.

The idea is to get the information from my API and then just display it. The API part is working, the displaying not that much.

My activity:

```
class User(val username: String, val display_name: String )

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var btnLogout: TextView
    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()


    fun getMyProfile(){
        // code that makes the request to my API is here!(and it's working)

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body= response.body()?.string()

                println(response.code())
                println(body)
                if(response.code()==200){
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    val my_user = gson.fromJson(body, User::class.java)
                    val view = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null, false)
                    val username: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.username)
                    val display_name: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.displayname)
                    username.text = my_user.username
                    display_name.text = my_user.display_name


                }
                if(response.code()==401){
                    // if the request is not allowed
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {



        val context:Context = baseContext
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_new_group, R.id.nav_new_channel,
                R.id.nav_contacts, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_send
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        getMyProfile()
        ...
    }
        ...





}
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
```

Both my_user.username and my_user.display_name have values(I have specifically checked).

Comment: Unless you add `view` to some parent, then your code isn't going to have any effect; you'll just inflate a view, update it, and throw it out. What does the larger code look like?

Comment: Post the entire activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
You have to create inflater and a ViewGroup.
So it becomes:

```
val inflater: LayoutInflater = this@MainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
val viewGroup : ViewGroup = findViewById (R.id.nav_view)
var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, viewGroup)
```

And the variables which point to the TextViews become:

```
var display_name: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.displayname)
var username: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.username)
```